# Why are these two calls different in python?

Tags: python

I'm just begin with python but I can understand why this to call get different result

```
from itertools import izip
a =  ['hello','world','1','2', 'other', 'thing']
b =  ['hello','world','1','2', 'other', 'thing']
i = iter(a)
i2= iter(b)
c = dict(izip(i, i2))
```

**Result:**

```
{'thing': 'thing', '1': '1', 'other': 'other', '2': '2', 'world': 'world', 'hello': 'hello'}
```

---

```
from itertools import izip
a =  ['hello','world','1','2', 'other', 'thing']
i = iter(a)
c = dict(izip(i, i))
```

**Result:**

```
{'1': '2', 'other': 'thing', 'hello': 'world'}
```

Comment: Same iterator vs different iterator.

Comment: Because in second case you've passed one iterator to `izip` function, and wile iterators are one shot iterables `izip` will consume the items from your actual iterable in an interleave manner. (two item at each iteration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *iterator* returned by `iter` will yield each element from the given iterable only once. You can imagine each iterator returned by `iter` as if there was a sign pointing to the next element. In the first excerpt you have 2 signs: `i` and `i2`, and in the second just one. An iterator supports a single operation called `next`, which will get the item that the "sign" is pointing to currently, and moves the "sign" so that it points to the following element.

---

`zip(p, q)` / `izip(p, q)` will internally get the next element from `p`, then from `q` and build a tuple of these elements, and yield it; and then repeat for as long as `p` and `q` both have `next` elements.

In the first case there are 2 independent iterators. So both `i` and `i2` will yield all the elements in their respective lists. I will present it here using simpler code and `zip` - as a bonus, this is Python 3 -compatible:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> p = iter(a)
>>> q = iter(a)
>>> list(zip(p, q))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

In the second case you passed in the *same* iterator twice. `izip` still thinks it has 2 iterators; so `izip` will first ask `p` for the `next` element, and then `q` for the `next` element - but there is only one iterator - so `izip` will see every second element coming from `p`, and every second from `q`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> p = iter(a)
>>> q = p
>>> q is p
True
>>> list(zip(p, q))
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Finally, `dict`, when given an *iterable* of tuples, will construct a dictionary with first element of each tuple becoming a key, and the second element becoming the value for that key. Thus:

```
>>> dict([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)])
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
```

and

```
>>> dict([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

---

By the way, this code is needlessly complicated:

```
a = ['hello', 'world', '1', '2', 'other', 'thing']
b = ['hello', 'world', '1', '2', 'other', 'thing']
i = iter(a)
i2= iter(b)
c = dict(izip(i, i2))
```

First of all, the list need not be duplicated - you can have 2 iterators iterate over the same list and they would work independently, i.e. you can have

```
i2 = iter(a)
```

and still get the same result, `b` is needless here.

Second, most of the time you don't need to create iterators explicitly - implicit will do. Thus the code for the first case could simply be written as

```
a = ['hello', 'world', '1', '2', 'other', 'thing']
c = dict(zip(a, a))
```